# Flutter convert Future<T> to List<T>

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I want to convert following

```
Future<UserDetl> f = AppDatabase().userById('55e62a90-273c-11ea-9441-f75d5cd0114b');
```

into `List<UserDetl> lstUser`

```
class UserDetl {
  String userId;
  String userName;
  String userPlace;
  String userUrl;

  UserDetl(this.userId,this.userName, this.userPlace, this.userUrl);

}
```

and I wanna get username from the list

```
String user = lstUser[0].userName;
```

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011075/return-a-list-from-a-future-in-flutter

Comment: that one using FutureBuilder method, and that method is only applicable to Future<List<T>>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting values from Future instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579358/getting-values-from-future-instances)

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
getUser() async {

UserDetl tmp = await  AppDatabase().userById('55e62a90-273c-11ea-9441-f75d5cd0114b');

if(tmp!=null)
 setState((){
    UserDetl u = v;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to build a list with your result:

```
Future<UserDetl> f = AppDatabase().userById('55e62a90-273c-11ea-9441-f75d5cd0114b');
UserDetl user = await f;
List<UserDetl> lstUser = [user];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<UserDetl> f = //get your Futuredata
UserDetl user = await f;
List<UserDetl> lstUser = [user];//add in list

//you also can get it from list like:

UserDetl user = lstUser[0];
```